# How to use R's RMariaDB:dbSendQuery() function with query VALUES contained in R variables?

Tags: mysql, r

```
library(DBI)
library(RMariaDB)
con <- dbConnect(RMariaDB::MariaDB(), host = "mysql", group = "mygroup")
```

#### Succeeds:

```
res <- dbSendQuery(con, "INSERT INTO sub_data (fname, lname, sex) VALUES ('Joe', 'Smith', 'male' )")
```

#### Fails:

```
fname1 <- "Joe"; lname1 <- "Smith";  sex1 <- "male"
res <- dbSendQuery(con, "INSERT INTO sub_data (fname, lname, sex) VALUES (fname1, lname1, sex1 )")
```

**Error in result_create(conn@ptr, statement) : 
  Unknown column 'fname1' in 'field list' [1054]**

Comment: You can use `sqlInterpolate` from package `DBI`.

Comment: Thanks, that works